# Setup Play 2.2.1 and IntelliJ 12.0.4

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, playframework-2.2

I am running on OSX 10.9. I have downloaded Play 2.2.1 and want to use IntelliJ 12.0.4. for development.
I set it up by running `play` in the directory of the project followed by `idea with-sources=yes` followed by a `compile`.

I can run the project from the terminal and from IntelliJ without any problems. All the changes I make to the files are reflected in the browser when the project is recompiled.

What troubles me is that IntelliJ cannot resolve the views which makes its auto-complete function useless. The error is "Cannot resolve method ok(?)/Cannot resolve symbol index".

I have read a great deal of material on the matter but to no avail. I would be grateful if anyone points out a step I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem on occasion; unfortunately I can't reproduce it now with any of my Play 2.2 projects, but I remember having to do this to get the views to resolve:

- Go to the Module Settings for your project in IntelliJ (select the top-level, hit F4)
- Choose the Modules item in the Project Structure window that appears
- Select the *<projectname>* item (as opposed to the *<projectname>-build*) item
- Add the *compiler's output* `views` directory to the **Source Folders** items;

  - I'm in Scala so for me it's `target/scala-2.10/classes/views`
  - I'm sure it'll be something fairly similar in Java - probably `target/classes/views`?
  - I personally find the IntelliJ UI for this to be very non-intuitive; you might need to take the `target` directory and/or one of its subdirectories out of the **Excluded Folders** first
- After applying that change, IntelliJ *should* see those view files as just-another source file, so auto-complete *should* work for them.

Answer (score 0):

Also it might be that the `Intellij` you are using is not the **Ultimate Edition**.

The community edition does not support `Play Framework` versions lower than `2.4.x`

look for 'play' here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html